# How to hide the div using timeout?

Tags: javascript

Here I am calling the JavaScript function which appends the text and image to div, now I want to div hide after 2 seconds. How can i do that?

code:

```
function showdiv(city, imagesrc, timeout) {

  window.setTimeout(function() {

    document.getElementById('city-order').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('order-product').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('product-list-display').style.display = "block";
    var order_placed_city = document.getElementById('city-order');
    var content = document.createTextNode(city);
    order_placed_city.appendChild(content);    
    var product_order = document.getElementById('order-product');
    var elem = document.createElement("img");
    product_order.appendChild(elem);
    elem.src = imagesrc;

  },timeout);

   document.getElementById('product-list-display').style.display = "none";

}
```

Comment: `showdiv('city', 'http://placehold.it/200x200', 2000)` - maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Currently is see code that does the following:

on `showDiv()`:

1. Hide `#product-list-display`
2. After `timeout`-ms append some content

You could simple add another `window.setTimeout` at the end of your timed function that hides the div.

```
function showdiv(city, imagesrc, timeout) {

  window.setTimeout(function() {
    /* ... */

    // You could add it here
    window.setTimeout(hideDiv)
  },timeout);

  /* ... */

}
```

and then add another function:

```
function hideDiv() {
    // Your hiding code here
}
```

I would like to suggest you take at look at a framework like for instance jQuery. This would increase readability and make it less complex.
https://jquery.com

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is probably what you're looking for?

```
function showdiv(city, imagesrc, timeout) {

    // Show div
    document.getElementById('city-order').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('order-product').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('product-list-display').style.display = "block";
    var order_placed_city = document.getElementById('city-order');
    var content = document.createTextNode(city);
    order_placed_city.appendChild(content);    
    var product_order = document.getElementById('order-product');
    var elem = document.createElement("img");
    product_order.appendChild(elem);
    elem.src = imagesrc;

  // Hide div after n milliseconds
  setTimeout(function() {
   document.getElementById('product-list-display').style.display = "none";      
  }, timeout);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use display: hidden if you just want to hide the element, display none if you want it to disappear entirely:

```
function hideDiv(elementID,timeout) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById(elementID).style.display = "none";
    },timeout);
}
```